# jQuery live validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a live validation script for a form. I've somewhat got it, I think anyway...but the error message comes up when there is text in the field as opposed to when there is no text. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid wrong, I'm pretty sure I have the if values right, `value == ''` is if value is nothing, `value !== ''` is if value is not nothing, right? Gah, maybe it's the on/change thing I should change? Hope you can help. Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vjwxs/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#name').on('change', function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (!this.value == '') {
            $("#errorname").fadeIn();
            $('#errorname').css("display", "inline-block");
            $('#errorname').css("color", "#838383");
            $('#errorname').css("background-color", "#fff568");
        }
        else if (!this.value !== '' ) {
            $("#errorname").fadeOut();
            $('#errorname').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you got rid of the first ! in each condition. `(this.value != '')` and `(this.value == '')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read your `if` conditions out loud. That should help you realise where the problem is:

```
if (!this.value == '') { /* Show the error */ }
```

"If *not* this value is equal to an empty string". Or, in a more understandable form, "If this value is *not* equal to an empty string". You actually want to show the error "if this value *is* equal to an empty string".

```
if (!this.value !== '' ) { /* Hide the error */ }
```

"If *not* this value is *not* equal to an empty string". And again, more readable, "If this value is *not not* equal to an empty string". You actually want to hide the error "if this value *is not* equal to an empty string".

Your code will work if you [remove the first negation from both conditions](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjwxs/4/).

Comment: Ah, thank you...knew it was something silly, god damn it haha. Thank you. I'll accept answer as soon as it will let me.